# ViewModel with related objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Relatively new to .Net MVC. Stumped by what appears to be a very simple problem.

I've got a few objects that are related to each other.

(as an example)

```
public class Asset{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public AssetCategory AssetCategory {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class AssetCategory{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public DateTime SomeDate{get;set;}
  public int Id{get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a new "Asset" object in my View and pre so I create an empty one with the AssetCategory set. Then pass it through as the model for that view.

I've tried having a `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory)`
Which obviously fails as it doesn't how how to convert from that object to a string and back.

If I have `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory.Id)` then my ModelState is valid, But doesn't have all the information tied to the AssetCategory.

In this situation, do I just have to get the correct versions of any detached objects from my DB?
As it stands, when I try to save my new Asset. I get an error because the non-nullable DateTime on the AssetCategory object is invalid.

Comment: Could you update your post with what your View uses for model, and the method (at least the parts relevant to the question) you post to.
But without seeing the actual method you post to, or what model your view uses, I would guess that you had to change `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory.Id)` to `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory_Id)`. That is under the assumption that m (the views Model) is `Asset`, and that `Asset` has a field (in the database) called AssetCategory_Id (or something similar).

Comment: Ben, as @MajorByte pointed out, your question is vague. please show your View and try to better explain your workflow.

Comment: @Ben pointed out, your question is vague. please show your View and try to better explain your workflow! I did my answer based on my experience and the cenario that you pointed out above! Looks like the AssetCategory has no data loaded, thats why you getting this error!

Comment: does not Custom Model Binder  solve your problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the category information on the server, then yes, get that on the server and attach to your object before saving it.

You should only include the AssetCategory in your model if your client will change it, ie. you have a dropdown the user can choose from.  In that case, add the id only and a list of valid items to your model.  When your model is posted back, convert it to the object  you need to save.

In other words, keep the classes you have to save to the db, but create a separate view model.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the Id then your original option would work (but as you said no other details known based of posted back data only).

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory.Id)
```

If you want more information that that, try to make it modular by using an EditorTemplate.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.AssetCategory)
```

*\Views\Assets\EditorTemplates\AssetCategory.cshtml*

```
@model AssetCategory
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Name)
```

That being said, you should be using ViewModels for this sort of thing not EntityModels. What I'd recommend is keep it as passing back only the Id, but then on your postback, load the full asset category info from the database using the AssetCategoryId prior to saving your Asset itself.

Answer (score -1):

For performance EF doesn't load all the data into the model by default. So, you have to load this manually like this:

```
 public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
 {
    var asset = db.Assets.Single(a => a.Id == Id).Include(a => a.AssetCategory);

    return View(asset);
 }
```

The `Include` method will load the related object into its model, so you will get all properties and `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AssetCategory.Id)` will have the `Id` filled with the correct data.

Take a look at [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb896272.aspx) for more EF Related information!

Hope Its help you!

Comment: @Ben pointed out, your question is vague. please show your View and try to better explain your workflow